# interchanging the order of $d/dt$ and $\partial/\partial x$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

The situation is as follows.

The variable $y$ is related to another variable $x$, by some function $f$; $f(x)=y$. Here, $x$ depends on $t$, and we define $x'(t)=v(t)$.

Then the book claims that:

"Using the fact that along any curve we have $ d\over{dt}$$ x=v$, we have $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} x=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$.

Could someone explain in detail what is happening here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should write $f(x(t)) = y$ or $f\cdot x(t)$

Comment: In the title you have $\partial/\partial x$, which does not appear in the question. And this is just too vague to be answered. Maybe the authors omitted a smoothness assumption on $f^{-1}$ and the "curves". Or maybe you did.